# Data upload size limit to API

Tags: javascript, java, file, api, file-upload

Suppose I want to upload a `CSV file` using javascript and send that file to my `REST API.`

What can be the **maximum size of the file** that I can **upload** which can be `handled by my API`?

I searched and somewhat got to know that file size cannot exceed **`10Mb.`**
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: are you using the `<input type="file">` tag?

Answer (score -1):

you can located the `input` tag using `document.querySelector` or using *jQuery* `$()` and in that tag there is a nested property called `size` (`input.files[0].size`) this property return the size of you file in a byte. from there all you need to is bind to the `onchange` event of the `input`, check the file size and if it's over **10MB** alert a message and clear the input

```js
document.querySelector('[type="file"]').addEventListener('change',function(e){
      if(e.target.files[0].size > 10000000){
         alert('file size greater then 10MB');
         e.target.value = null
      }
    })
```

```html
<input type="file"/>
```

Comment: So only 10mb size of data can be handled by the API in java?  or can it be more than 10mb   like 1GB or something?

Comment: Your answer is much appreciated. 
I want to know the numbers here.  The file size that client side can take in and send to the api.

Comment: the client and the server upload an unlimited size of file... all depended on the server